# MySQL to SQL Server, How to replicate data in a set interval?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

What would be the best way to replicate a database with several tables from a MySQL server to a MSSQL server, seeing as they are in different devices on the same network with a set interval of 10 minutes?

By best way, I mean a way that wouldn't completely copy all the rows with each iteration, a way that would only copy the latest entries since the last iteration.

Comment: "Best way" based on what requirements? That's a "what's the best car" kind of question

Comment: In any case, the term is replication, not migration

Comment: Your definition of best doesn't really explain anything, it's the minimum requirement and depends on *MySQL* features, or lack of

Comment: Thank you for the tips, will give the dba.se a try.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904447/replication-between-sql-server-and-mysql-server

Comment: If your tables have a unique incrementing key you could try querying for MySQL records whose value is greater than the greatest ID stored on SQL Server's side. That won't detect modifications or deletions though

Comment: After trying those steps on the link above I might also try a python script that verifies by ID. Thanks for the help

Comment: @BryceSoker using a linked server will be faster - load every row whose ID is greater than X. Using Python to check row by row is the *slowest* way possible.  Operations like this are called RBAR - Row By Agonizing Row. Pulling all ID values on the target server and using an outer join with the target table will be a lot faster - all MySQL rows will be accessed, just like Python would do, but *only* the IDs would be copied. The JOIN would be able to use indexes to find deleted rows very quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As listed in the comments Linked Server is the best connection method, it integrates into your views and stored procedures.

The way I have done it in situations like this is create a view or a job on the source database that filters out the changed rows.  I have gone as far as using temporary tables on the MySQL side, then from the MSSQL side read the temporary table you created. If you created joins in a query on the MSSQL side looking at the MySQL, the MySQL will just send all of the data over and MSSQL will have to process it, that's what you are trying to avoid.  You just want the changed data.

Another method probably is the easiest is to create matching tables on the MSSQL side and use a product list SQL Data Examiner, then set the command line utility to run a project in the task scheduler. http://www.sqlaccessories.com/sql-data-examiner/  This will compare the actual data on both tables.  If you are talking millions of rows or a slow connection this isn't the way.  Just like doing it all in MSSQL you will have the issue where it pulls all of the data for the comparison.

So the best way depends on how many tables, how much data, and the connection capabilities.  The easiest would be SQL Data Examiner.